Microservices inbox-outbox pattern
I have a question I'm curious about. Let's say we are developing a microservice social media application (I chose this topic for practical purposes :)). I'm using the inbox-outbox pattern to ensure data consistency. When using the outbox pattern, I save the PostOutbox entity within the PostContext, and then I check this database with a worker service and a job. What I'm curious about is: Should I define a common worker service for handling this process for both posts and comments (i.e., sending events), or should I define separate worker services for each? Of course, defining them separately is more manageable, but I wonder how this is used in a professional context. Thank you!

